# Rhythmbox displays tracks out of order

Tags: music, rhythmbox, multimedia, music-player

[screenshot of rhythmbox displaying tracks out of order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyeQX.png)

Really messes up my album-listening experience. I just wanna play some ICP. WHOOP WHOOP! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to click any of the headings to Sort the songs.

Click Track.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that! Thank you so much!